# Apollo Federation Integration testing and extended types in subgraphs

Tags: testing, graphql, integration-testing, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I'm currently trying to write a simple integration test to run executeOperation on one of my subgraphs. However, the graphql schema for my subraph has entity references to my other subgraphs. For Example, this block in in the .graphql for the subgraph I'm testing.

```
extend type Collection @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String! @external
  itemId: Int
}
```

When I try to run my test method I get the following errors (fyi, ContentId is a custom scalar defined in the same schema file):

```
Unknown type "Collection". Did you mean "ContentId"?
Cannot extend type "Collection" because it is not defined. Did you mean "ContentId"?
Unknown directive "@key".
Unknown directive "@external".
```

I'm assuming this is because the test can't reference the entities in the other subgraphs. The documentation isn't very clear. Is there some way I'm supposed to mock this, or some other solution for integration testing in a federated setup?